# How can I autofill the email field on paypal?

Tags: php, html, email, paypal, autofill

I have a button linked to this page:  https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/send-money-online

I'd like for the 'To (Their email address)' field to be autofilled with my email, so that my clients won't have to enter it.

I've tried using this url 'https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/send-money-online?email=johndoe@email.com'

I've also tried this code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_send-money" method="POST" target="paypal">
<input type="hidden" value="_send-money" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="United States">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="johndoe@email.com">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/mktg/logo/AM_mc_vs_dc_ae.jpg" border="0"
name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it’s fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

but it goes to the old Paypal Send Money page and the email field is still not autofilled.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in the UK:

`https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_send-money&amount=10.00&amount_ccode=GBP&cmd=_send-money&email=receiver%40paypalemail.co.uk&payment_source=p2p_mktgpage&payment_type=Payment%20Owed&sender_email=sender%40paypalemail.co.uk&type=external`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe email you use may already have a Paypal account.